# Android 11 GooglePlayServicesUtilLight crash

Tags: android

The app starts crashing on Android 11 devices(100% background)

[Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww40B.png)

Message: "The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 12451000 but found 4323000".
I have already defined the correct value inside the manifest file as follows:

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I tried to use `tools:replace="android:value"` and dependency updates.

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0'

    implementation(name: 'ALIBDateTimePicker-release', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'ALIBFancyCoverFlow-release', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'ALIBParalloid-release', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'ALIBParalloidViews-release', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'ALIBTiltEffect-release', ext: 'aar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-lang3_3.3.2_shrinked.jar')
    implementation files('libs/android-viewbadger.jar')
    implementation files('libs/GoogleConversionTrackingSdk-2.2.4.jar')

    implementation 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'

    implementation 'org.scribe:scribe:1.3.7'

    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:19.1.0"

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'

    runtimeOnly 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.10.9'
    implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:8.2.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
    }
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.12.16'

    implementation 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'

    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.3.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.7.0'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.20'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.7'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.27'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'

    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.16"

    implementation 'com.vimeo.stag:stag-library:2.6.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.vimeo.stag:stag-library-compiler:2.6.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    implementation 'com.xwray:groupie:2.0.3'
    implementation('net.opacapp:multiline-collapsingtoolbar:1.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    implementation 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:1.5.0'

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-support-v4:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-design:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-recyclerview-v7:2.2.0'

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0"

    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4+@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2'
    implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.8.5'

    implementation 'com.annimon:stream:1.2.1'

    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0'

    implementation ('com.salesforce.service:chat-ui:4.1.2') {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
    }

    implementation 'com.forter.mobile:fortersdk:2.4.6@aar'

    releaseImplementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0"
    releaseImplementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.0"
    releaseImplementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0"

    implementation('com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    // Firebase for OneSignal (crash on first launch without this)
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1"

    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.15.0'
    implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:16.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

The crash disappeared after deleting the proguard.